# Difficulty With Register Route, not able to register without image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication

In the User model I have set avatar to be not required

```
avatar: {
    public_id: {
      type: String,
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
```

but still if I register without image it shows error **POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/register 500 (Internal Server Error)** and REGISTER_USER_FAIL constant state is returned

Here is my UserController.jsx, Register Route

```
exports.registerUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
    folder: "avatars",
    width: 150,
    crop: "scale",
  });

  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  if(req.body.avatar){
    const user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password,
      avatar: {
        public_id: myCloud.public_id,
        url: myCloud.secure_url,
      },
    });
    sendToken(user, 201, res);
  } else {
    const user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password
    });
    sendToken(user, 201, res);
  }
});
```

SignUp Component

```
import React, {Fragment,useRef,useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./LoginSignUp.css";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import LockOpenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOpen';
import EmailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Email';
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import img from "../../images/Profile.png";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {clearErrors, login , register} from "../../actions/userAction.jsx";
import {useAlert} from "react-alert";
 

export default function LoginSignUp() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const alert = useAlert();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
  
    const { error, loading, isAuthenticated } = useSelector(
      (state) => state.user
    );
  
    const loginTab = useRef(null);
    const registerTab = useRef(null);
    const switcherTab = useRef(null);
  
    const [loginEmail, setLoginEmail] = useState("");
    const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState("");
  
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    });
  
    const { name, email, password } = user;
  
    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(img);
    const [avatarPreview, setAvatarPreview] = useState(img);
  
    const loginSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      dispatch(login(loginEmail, loginPassword));
    };
  
    const registerSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      const myForm = new FormData();
  
      myForm.set("name", name);
      myForm.set("email", email);
      myForm.set("password", password);
      if(avatar!==img){
        myForm.set("avatar", avatar);
      }
      dispatch(register(myForm));
    };
  
    const registerDataChange = (e) => {
      if (e.target.name === "avatar") {
        const reader = new FileReader();
  
        reader.onload = () => {
          if (reader.readyState === 2) {
            setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
            setAvatar(reader.result);
          }
        };
        if(reader){
          reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        }
      } else {
        setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      }
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (error) {
        alert.error(error);
        dispatch(clearErrors());
      }
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        navigate("/");
      }
    }, [dispatch, error, alert, navigate, isAuthenticated]);
  
    const switchTabs = (e, tab) => {
      if (tab === "login") {
        switcherTab.current.classList.add("shiftToNeutral");
        switcherTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToRight");
  
        registerTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToNeutralForm");
        loginTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToLeft");
      }
      if (tab === "register") {
        switcherTab.current.classList.add("shiftToRight");
        switcherTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToNeutral");
  
        registerTab.current.classList.add("shiftToNeutralForm");
        loginTab.current.classList.add("shiftToLeft");
      }
    };
  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {loading ? (
          <Loader />
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            <div className="LoginSignUpContainer">
              <div className="LoginSignUpBox">
                <div>
                  <div className="login_signUp_toggle">
                    <p onClick={(e) => switchTabs(e, "login")}>LOGIN</p>
                    <p onClick={(e) => switchTabs(e, "register")}>REGISTER</p>
                  </div>
                  <button ref={switcherTab}></button>
                </div>
                <form className="loginForm" ref={loginTab} onSubmit={loginSubmit}>
                  <div className="loginEmail">
                    <EmailIcon />
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      required
                      value={loginEmail}
                      onChange={(e) => setLoginEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="loginPassword">
                    <LockOpenIcon />
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      required
                      value={loginPassword}
                      onChange={(e) => setLoginPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <Link to="/password/forgot">Forget Password ?</Link>
                  <input type="submit" value="Login" className="loginBtn" />
                </form>
                <form
                  className="signUpForm"
                  ref={registerTab}
                  encType="multipart/form-data"
                  onSubmit={registerSubmit}
                >
                  <div className="signUpName">
                    <PersonIcon />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Name"
                      required
                      name="name"
                      value={name}
                      onChange={registerDataChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="signUpEmail">
                    <EmailIcon />
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      required
                      name="email"
                      value={email}
                      onChange={registerDataChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="signUpPassword">
                    <LockOpenIcon />
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      required
                      name="password"
                      value={password}
                      onChange={registerDataChange}
                    />
                  </div>
  
                  <div id="registerImage">
                    <img src={avatarPreview} alt="Avatar Preview" />
                    <input
                      type="file"
                      name="avatar"
                      accept="image/*"
                      onChange={registerDataChange}
                    />
                    <span>*image size less than 500KB</span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Register" className="signUpBtn" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
```

1. Register route works fine only if I use image while registering.
2. When registering without image

Answer (score 0):

```
// v-- seems you are using avatar before checking if it's in the body
const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, { 
    folder: "avatars",
    width: 150,
    crop: "scale",
  });

  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  if(req.body.avatar){
```